# JS map / filter set property on self

Tags: javascript

Would like to use a one-liner to set property inside of an object / array using `map` or `filter` iterations

Currently the code looks like so (an example query params extraction)...

```
var q = {};

var q = location.search.substr(1).split('&').map(function(a){
    q[a.split('=')[0]] = a.split('=')[1] // q must be defined primarily?!
});
```

Is there a workaround to accomplish this without pre-defining `q` variable, maybe somewhere in the vicinity of

```
var q = location.search.substr(1).split('&').map(function(a){
    this[a.split('=')[0]] = a.split('=')[1] // this doesn't work obviously
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not use `URLSearchParams` instead?

Comment: `URLSearchParams` IE says no compatibility - but this is a more general question whether this even possible, this might be useful for many other things. the query params extraction is just a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```js
const locationSearch = '?a=b&c=d&e=f';

const q = locationSearch.substr(1).split('&').reduce((acc, x) => {
  const [key, value] = x.split('=');
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(q);
```

I've used some ES6 features in this answer: [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Unfortunately these features aren't supported by IE10, so you have to either transpile your code with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or don't use these features. The code below should work in IE10:

```js
var locationSearch = '?a=b&c=d&e=f';

var q = locationSearch.substr(1).split('&').reduce(function (acc, x) {
  var keyAndValue = x.split('=');
  var key = keyAndValue[0];
  var value = keyAndValue[1];
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(q);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a closure and add an destructed array.

```js
var q = Object.assign(...'foo=bar&baz=42'
        .split('&')
        .map(s => (([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))(s.split('=')))
    );
        
console.log(q);
```

Here for ES5

```js
var q = 'foo=bar&baz=42'
        .split('&')
        .reduce(function (o, s) {
            return function (kv) {
                o[kv[0]] = kv[1];
                return o;
            }(s.split('='));
        }, {});
        
console.log(q);
```

Comment: oh no, it is ES6.

Comment: Check out @Michal Perlakowski's answer, its just few characters shorter ;) - but the solution is the same! I have shortened it to `var q = location.search.substr(1).split('&').reduce(function(a,b){a[b.split('=')[0]] = b.split('=')[1];return a;},{});` and while the inner function is a cleaner solution, shorter is my personal preference...

Comment: i took the first approach and made it working for earlier version of JS. size does not matter, for me, in this case.